# Working with personalized operators on MongoDb find() method

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm in trouble with a query result, where I want to compare the value of a field, multiplying and comparing with other system value.

Its like this:

```
var servicePriceProportion = 0.7;
var serviceMaxPrice = 1000;

        CollectionX.find({
        ... other conditions,
        $where: function(){
            return (this.Data.investmentMax * servicePriceProportion < serviceMaxPrice);
        }
        });
```

I have tried, too. But dont worked:

```
 $where: function(){
                return (this.Data.investmentMax != this.Data.investmentMax);
```

}

The $where condition simply dont works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using javascript variables into the `$where`, you should refer them with the `obj` keyword.

```
$where: "this.Data.investmentMax * " + servicePriceProportion + " < " + serviceProviderMaxPrice"
```

so `this` refers to the actual data into the collection, `obj` instead refer another variables.

You should know that using the $where operator could do the querys pretty slowness.

A Note from the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where).

> In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your
>   query using another operator

So in resume, if there is some way to accomplish this without using `$where`, it will be nice for the application

Comment: what did you get? you get the full query? without the `$where` conditional?

Comment: looking into docs this will don't work. you can't use nested documents so ttry with `this.investmentMax` because `this.data.investmentMax` will not work/ *Only apply the $where query operator to top-level documents.*

Comment: The same result when it is out of the condition $where. As if the $where conditional did not exist. For test, works with:  $where: "this.Data.investmentMax != this.Data.investmentMax" } ); Strange

Comment: so it seems like its not taking the 2 javascript variables right?

Comment: Yep... Its because "Only apply the $where query operator to top-level documents."? Have another solution?

Comment: why don't put that 2 numbers into a object field and use it like this.Data.servicePriceProportion since i think (by the name) the values will be static.

Comment: Maybe its not possible , because different users see different information for the same document , based on personal information. So I need change the values dinamically.

Comment: Try using `$where` only, without the other conditions,  `CollectionX.find( { $where: function() { this.Data.investmentMax * obj.servicePriceProportion < obj.serviceMaxPrice } } );`, also be sure that the variables are on the same file where you have the query

Comment: Dont works. Return all data. I tried do a new test: return (this.Data.investmentMax * 2 < 1) And return all documents too.

Comment: Now I tried something simpler , but returned all documents.

           $where: function(){
                return (this._id == "A6QK4NJuheGsnue6n")
            }

Comment: But with this, works: $where: "this._id == 'A6QK4NJuheGsnue6n'"

The problem its with the javascript function.

Comment: Try again with the other options with obj. But wrapp all into ""

Comment: worked! Please, update your answer.

$where: "this.Data.investmentMax * " + servicePriceProportion + " < " + serviceProviderMaxPrice. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!